# How to filter Gmail threads with fewer than certain number of replies?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I'm trying to create a filter to label Gmail threads that have fewer than a certain number of replies. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

No, I'm afraid there isn't. Filters only work on a relatively small set of properties; number of replies isn't one of them.

I suppose a script built in Google Scripts *might* be able to find and label conversations based on number of replies, but there's not a way to do it with Gmail all by itself.